# How to use the social media API's for mobile apps development

Tags: facebook, api, twitter, linkedin-api, marmalade

I am new to mobile apps development. While using web marmalade for development I want to connect my app with social media websites.

All websites require authentication. after authentication they redirect to the server where application is hosted. The problem is mobile app is not hosted on a server like web apps. So I do not have the redirect URL. How Can I authenticate from Facebook , twitter and linkedIn without redirect URL's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web-Marmalade is based on Phonegap api. So you can use any phonegap plugin in marmalade too. Although marmalade is based on an older phonegap api, but still most of the plugin will work. [Here's](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) an example of facebook plugin from phonegap's github page.

You can check out the plugin making guide of web-marmalade [here](http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/web/plugins/webpluginsstepbystep.html).